# Is it possible to add an action to the summary of a bundled notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-7.0-nougat

I am using bundled notifications to group notifications by type. This works quite fine from a user's point of view when notifications are maximised, as shown below:

[image]

This does not work too well however when the child notifications are collapsed within the summary:

[image]

Now, given that the same `REGISTER` action can be performed on all the notifications in this group, I would like to give the user the possibility to carry out all these by simply tapping on a `REGISTER ALL` action in the summary notification. Adding actions to the summary however seems to have no effect. The code below - which is what I'm currently using - shows that the action on the summary notification is simply ignored:

```
final PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, RegisterAllService.getRegisterAllServiceIntent(),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        final NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "register all", actionIntent);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(action)
                .setGroup("confirmgroup")
                .setGroupSummary(true);


NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext()).notify(0, builder.build());


for(MyNotification myNotification: myNotifications){

    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    final PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, RegisterService.getRegisterServiceIntent(),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    final NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "register", actionIntent);


    NotificationCompat.Builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification)
                    .setContentTitle(myNotification.getTitle())
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(myNotification.getSubtitle()))
                    .setTicker(myNotification.getSubtitle())
                    .setContentText(myNotification.getSubtitle())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .addAction(action)
                    .setGroup("confirmgroup")
                    .setGroupSummary(false)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext()).notify(myNotification.getId(), builder.build());

}
```

Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. The feature was put on hold because it was just not worth the effort.

Comment: Now, Did you find the solution?